# Call Derived Class Method if derived class exists

Tags: c#

I have an Interface

```
interface ISampleInterface 
{
     void  SampleMethod();
}
```

and a class which is inherited from interface

```
public class ImplementationClass : ISampleInterface
{
    // Explicit interface member implementation: 
    public virtual void SampleMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}
public class derived : ImplementationClass
{
    public override void SampleMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("child");
    }
}
```

Now i want to call `SampleMethod` from derived class if user creates derived     class if not then call from `ImplementationClass` which is base class,
basically i have to decide at run time weather derived class exists with the `SampleMethod` implementation if yes go and call else go to base `SampleMethod`.

Comment: If your object is an instance of `derived`, calling `SampleMethod` will call the one in `derived`, can you please clarify what you want done that the code currently doesn't do?

Comment: Also as a note where you have said "Explicit interface member implementation" you have in fact implemented it implicitly.

Comment: i want to call SampleMethod from Derived class
but derived class is created by some other modules, i have to check weather the derived class exists Or not if it exists call derived method else call base mathod

Comment: You may want to read about [`virtual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4(v=vs.140).aspx#Anchor_0) methods first.

Comment: `ISampleInterface o = new ImplementationClass()` => `o.SampleMethod()` will output "Base". `ISampleInterface o = new derived()` (You should stick to the commonly accepted naming conventions btw) => `o.SampleMathod()` will output "child". So you already have your desired behavior.

Comment: Simply put - there's no checking required here.  You call `SampleMethod()` on whatever instance you're working with.  The only other scenario I can think of is if a user has created an instance of both ImplentationClass and Derived and you want to always call SampleMethod() from Derived (even if working with the instance of ImplementationClass).  If that is the case then I would suggest a different strategy.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to call SampleMethod from Derived class but derived class is created by some other modules, i have to check weather the derived class exists Or not if it exists call derived method else call base mathod

Per the comments on your question, this code is already working as you've described - because of polymorphism, the created object will call it's most relevant method.

In your case you override the virtual method of it's base class so that's the method that will be called.

Comment: To OP, *" i have to check"* - nope, you don't have to, simply call the method, `virtual` + `override` will do the rest.